# Accessing a Process's Memory Region

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, ptrace

I am trying to learn how to access the memory region of a process in order to print the start and end addresses of the code, its data regions, and the start and end of the heap.
I believe that **/proc/$pid/maps** contains the process's start and end memory regions but I am wondering if there is another way. Perhaps ptrace() ?

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/$pid/maps`  or `/proc/$pid/smaps` is the best, but linux specific, way to get the information about process address space mapping.

You could use `/proc/$pid/mem` to access the memory regions (be careful to `lseek` to appropriate regions, or to use `mmap` to access it).

Comment: It probably only exists in kernel land. So, no. On linux the `/proc` filesystem is the preferred way to query process- (and some system-) related things.